# If wallet A interacted with a smart contract, is it possible to transfer ownership to wallet B in order to interact with the same contract instead?

Tags: wallets

Scenario:

- Wallet A got hacked.
- Wallet A is used in a smart contract where there are funds invested.
- Wallet A cannot be used to withdraw funds from this contract as the funds are immediately flushed from the wallet when we do this.

Is it possible to transfer ownership to another address (wallet B), so that we can withdraw funds from the contract using wallet B?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer yes, if the wallet B is not compromised.

If **Wallet A** is owner of the contract, You need to call `transferOwnership`  by giving **Wallet B** address.